# screen-prints started failing recently in Ubuntu 16.04 in Virtualbox 5.2.18

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, print-screen

The first time I press PrtScr it generates a picture of the log-in background instead of the current window.  The second time it hangs with the entire screen dimmed.

I have tried several combinations of Shift, Ctrl and Alt with the PrtScr button and when the guest reacts, it is when the host key is active.  Every result was the same default background image rather than the current window, current workspace or even the current workspace background.

There are two saved images from several months ago of successful screenprints.  I have been regularly updating the guest with all current security and general updates.  This guest also gets re-booted several times a week.

Answer (score 0):

You have press the **host key** to make the prtscr is not intercepted by the host system. While the host key is activated (<kbd>Right CTRL</kbd> in the following example) your prtscr will be not intercepted by the host, and will be captured by the guest 
[host key activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2dOh.png)

While the host key is not activated, your ptrscr will be intercepted by the host. [host key not activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqdR7.png)

You can configure the host key in the following menu: [host key configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f1GT.png)